# hiii can any one have solution of this flutter problem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I/flutter (19413): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

I/flutter (1943): The following assertion was thrown building LoginScreen(dirty, state:
I/flutter (19413): LoginScreenState#0e365(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)):
I/flutter (19413): type '() => void' is not a subtype of type '() => Future

Comment: Please add additional information about the problem you are having. What is the line of code at line 845 of binding.dart? If you add more context to your post, you can avoid getting downvotes and improve your chance of getting an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Future that returns type database for your initDB() method:

```
Future<Database> initDB() async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, "event.db");
    var theDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDatabase;
}
```

Like Gene said in the comment, in order to properly help, we need more context, but I'm pretty sure that this is the issue. Let me know if that works.